# DOM not updating when click/tap event is executed using Ionic and Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, angular8

I'm using the directive `*ngFor` to load ionic-card components on to the DOM from an array named `userData`.  The `userData` array is composed of  nested objects with properties of id, title, and count.

I'm trying to create an on click/tap event that whenever the user taps on the card the count increments the specific card that was tapped.

The problem I'm having is that the `*ngFor` is not being updated when I click on the card.  But it does work when I just reference the count outside the *ngFor directive.

I would like to use the `*ngFor` directive and update each card individually when I click them.  Any help is much appreciated.

**Tally component HTML template paste**

```
<ion-card class="ion-card-custom" (click)="increaseCount()" *ngFor="let tal of userData">
       <ion-item>
           <ion-icon name="pin" slot="start" ></ion-icon>
           <ion-label>{{ tal.title }}</ion-label>
           <section class="tally-info-count" >{{ tal.count }} </section>
           <section class="tally-info-count" >{{ tap }} </section>
           <ion-button fill="outline" slot="end" class="info-button"> i </ion-button>
       </ion-item>
       <ion-item>
           <ion-label>{{ tal.created }} </ion-label>
           <p (click)="increaseCount()">{{ plus }} </p>
       </ion-item>
</ion-card>

<ion-card (tap)="tapEvent($event)">
    <ion-item>
      Tapped: {{tap}} times
    </ion-item>
  </ion-card>
```

**Full Tally Component Paste**

```
import { getLocaleDateTimeFormat } from '@angular/common';

//decorator
@Component({
    selector: 'app-tally',
    templateUrl: 'tally.html',
    styleUrls: ['tally.scss'],
  })

  export class Tally implements OnInit {
    title: string;
   public count: number = 0; 
   public tap: number = 0;
    plus: number; 
    userData: any[];
    id: number;
    //date created
    dateTime: Date = new Date();
    created: string = `${this.dateTime.getUTCMonth() +1}/${this.dateTime.getDay}/${this.dateTime.getUTCFullYear()}`

    constructor() { this.plus = 0;}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.title = "Title";
        this.userData = [
            {
                id: this.id,
                title: this.title,
                count: this.tap,
                created: this.created
            },
            {
                id: this.id,
                title: this.title,
                count: this.count,
                created: this.created
            }
        ]

    }

    increaseCount () {
        this.count += 1;
        this.plus += 1;
        console.log('this.count:', this.count);
    }

    tapEvent(e) {
        console.log(e);
        this.tap++;
      }
  }
```

Comment: The post is a bit confusing to me.. can you rephrase the question or reiterate it?

Comment: yes.  Sorry,  I'll rephrase.

Comment: I rephrased it, but I'm also going to leave a much smaller question here.  What I really want to do is essentially do is have each card increment whenever they are clicked or tapped.  I want each card to be able to only increment if it is clicked, not any other cards.  I hope this helps.  And thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments it looks like you are not updating the correct counters. When you loop over the userData in the template, you need to update the correct data it is referencing, not extra properties that you have created that are not accomplishing anything.

First off we need to keep track of the index in the ngFor so we know what user to update

```
<ng-template *ngFor="let tal of userData; let i = index;">
<ion-card class="ion-card-custom" (click)="increaseCount(i)">
    <ion-item>
        <ion-icon name="pin" slot="start" ></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>{{ tal.title }}</ion-label>
        <section class="tally-info-count" >{{ tal.count }} </section>
        <section class="tally-info-count" >{{ tap }} </section>
        <ion-button fill="outline" slot="end" class="info-button"> i </ion-button>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
        <ion-label>{{ tal.created }} </ion-label>
        <p> {{ plus }} </p>
    </ion-item>
</ion-card>
```

I have added the index to the ngFor so we know which index of the user we are looking at. The other change is I put the ngFor on an ngTemplate. Sometimes putting it on a component can cause problems, so I sometimes do this just to be safe. Lastly I am passing in the index into `(click)="increaseCount(i)"` that way we know which userData to update. Next we need to update your component code and get rid of some of the data that wasn't useful.

```
import { getLocaleDateTimeFormat } from '@angular/common';

//decorator
@Component({
    selector: 'app-tally',
    templateUrl: 'tally.html',
    styleUrls: ['tally.scss'],
  })

export class Tally implements OnInit {
  userData: any[];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    const dateTime: Date = new Date();
    const created: string = `${dateTime.getUTCMonth() +1}/${dateTime.getDay}/${dateTime.getUTCFullYear()}`;
    this.userData = [
        {
            id: 0,
            title: "Title1",
            count: 0,
            created: created
        },
        {
            id: 1,
            title: "Title2",
            count: 0,
            created: created
        }
    ]

  }

  increaseCount (index: number) {
    const specificUserData = this.userData[index];
    specificUserData.count++;
  }
}
```

I removed the properties because they were not useful, since the data needs to live in userData. Then I'm using the index that were are passing in from the template to determine which userData we need to modify. There are other ways to do this, but this is probably the simplest way given the way you have your project set up.

Comment: Thank you everyone!!  I'm very new to Angular and I was handling this completely wrong!

Answer (score 0):

You're updating `this.count` and not `tal.count`.

```
<ion-card class="ion-card-custom" (click)="increaseCount(tal)" *ngFor="let tal of userData">

increaseCount (tal: any) {
    tal.count += 1;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I identify two fallacies in your code:

1. In `increaseCount()` and `tapEvent()` you increase `this.count` and `this.tap` respectively. But `this` in this context refers to the `Component` and not to a specific user/card. Therefore `{{ tap }}` in the template will be the same value for *all* cards, which is why your counters are "not updated *individually*".
2. You initialize the `userData` with:

```js
this.userData = [
    {
        id: this.id,
        title: this.title,
        count: this.tap,
        created: this.created
    },
    {
        id: this.id,
        title: this.title,
        count: this.count,
        created: this.created
    }
]
```

which initializes the `count` property with the **value** of `this.tap` and `this.count` respectively, i.e. 0.

But what this does **not** do is **bind** the property value to `this.tap` or `this.count`, i.e. changing the values in `increaseCount()` or `tapEvent()` does **not** affect the `count` properties of the `userData` items.

This is why "the `*ngFor` is not being updated when [you] click on the card".

In order to get the intended behavior here you need to pass the *current* `tal` instance within the `*ngFor` loop to `increaseCount()` like this:

```html
<ion-card class="ion-card-custom" (click)="increaseCount(tal)" *ngFor="let tal of userData">
       ...
</ion-card>
```

and instead of incrementing `this.count` of the `Component` you need to increment the `count` property of the passed object:

```js
increaseCount(tal) {
    tal.count++;
}
```

Instead of passing the object you may also use the index as suggested by [@Derek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57581999/11932806).